# Python list is not callable

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask

I have a function in a Flask app that returns some API data

```
def fetch_trains():
    r = requests.get('https://developer.trimet.org/ws/v2/vehicles/appID/[app id goes here]')
    vehicles = r.json()
    listOfVehicles = []
    for vehicle in vehicles['resultSet']['vehicle']:
        if vehicle['type'] =='rail':
            vehToAdd = Train()

            vehToAdd.bearing = vehicle['bearing']
            vehToAdd.blockID = vehicle['blockID']
            vehToAdd.delay = vehicle['delay']
            vehToAdd.direction = vehicle['direction']
            vehToAdd.extraBlockID = vehicle['extraBlockID']
            vehToAdd.gararge = vehicle['garage']
            vehToAdd.inCongestion = vehicle['inCongestion']
            vehToAdd.latitude = vehicle['latitude']
            vehToAdd.longitude = vehicle['longitude']
            vehToAdd.lastLocID = vehicle['lastLocID']
            vehToAdd.offRoute = vehicle['offRoute']
            vehToAdd.signMessageLong = vehicle['signMessageLong']
            vehToAdd.time = vehicle['time']
            vehToAdd.tripID = vehicle['tripID']
            vehToAdd.vehicleID = vehicle['vehicleID']
            vehToAdd.nextLocID = vehicle['nextLocID']
            listOfVehicles.append(vehToAdd)
    #return jsonify({'List of vehicles':listOfVehicles})
    return listOfVehicles
```

The above listOfVehicles isn't returned in the API call, rather I get the enigmatic

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Now, if I comment out the last line, and uncomment the jsonify line, that works. *But* parsing that returned object in the front end is a pain. I'd like to just return listOfVehicles, but I don't know why its not letting me.

Edited:
I forgot the Train class defined above:

```
class Train:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bearing = None
        self.blockID = None
        self.delay = None
        self.direction = None
        self.extraBlockID = None
        self.garage = None
        self.inCongestion = False
        self.latitude = None
        self.longitude = None
        self.lastLocID = None
        self.nextLocID = None
        self.offRoute = False
        self.signMessageLong = None
        self.time = None
        self.tripID = None
        self.vehicleID = None

    def __html__(self):
        return {
            "Bearing": self.bearing,
            "BlockID": self.blockID,
            "Delay": self.delay,
            "Direction": self.direction,
            "extraBlockID": self.extraBlockID,
            "Garage": self.garage,
            "inCongestion": self.inCongestion,
            "Latitude": self.latitude,
            "Longitude": self.longitude,
            "lastLocID": self.lastLocID,
            "nextLocID": self.nextLocID,
            "offRoute": self.offRoute,
            "signMessageLong": self.signMessageLong,
            "time": self.time,
            "vehicleID": self.vehicleID,
            "TripID": self.tripID
        }
```

EDIT2:
Calls fetch_trains():

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/get_trains', methods=['GET', 'OPTIONS'])
def get_trains():
    train_list = fetch_trains()

    return train_list
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the caller of `fetch_trains`...

Comment: I think the problem lies outside the scope of what you've posted here.

Comment: How so? What path should I take?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that your code is trying to return a `list`. Flask doesn't expect to return `list` object from view function, but `response` object, refer to [official doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#about-responses). `jsonify` is working as it returns a JSON response object.

If you want to just return listOfVehicles, you can assign it to a variable, then render it to template, like this:

```
from flask import render_template

def get_trains():
    train_list = fetch_trains()

    #return train_list
    return render_template('index.html', train_list=train_list)
```

In templates `index.html`:

```
{% for train in train_list %}
    {{train}}</br>
{% endfor %}
```

It will for loop over `train_list`, display all in `index.html`.